# MySQL error #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using MySQL and I am defining a stored procedure like this:

```
delimiter ;;
Create procedure sp_test()

  select * from name_table;
end
```

When I try to execute that procedure I get this error:

```
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

What does this mean and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a typo as you have an `END` but no `BEGIN`. The message you get is most likely a bug in whatever tool you were using. You would not get this message when executing this from normal MySQL CLI.

Answer (score 19):

From the reference manual section [B.3.2.12 Commands out of sync](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html):

> ##### B.3.2.12 Commands out of sync
>
> If you get `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` in your client code, you are calling client
> functions in the wrong order.
>
> This can happen, for example, if you are using `mysql_use_result()` and
> try to execute a new query before you have called `mysql_free_result()`.
> It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data
> without calling `mysql_use_result()` or `mysql_store_result()` in between.

This [post from the MySQL forums](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?108,4380,4470#msg-4470) has this to say:

> I've solved that problem. I use MySQL-Fron instead MySQL Query
> browser. And everything works fine.

Makes me think that it's not a server or database problem but a problem in the tool you're using.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I had the following structure in my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS processcolumns;
    CREATE PROCEDURE processcolumns ()
    BEGIN
        (...)
    END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL processcolumns ();
DROP PROCEDURE processcolumns;
```

The problem relies here: `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS processcolumns;`
I removed the semi colon `;` and replaced it with the delimiter `//` like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS processcolumns //
```

And it's now solved!

Comment: This works perfectly for me, just need to put the new delimiter at the end of the DROP command. Thanks for the simple solution, although I didn't how it solve the issue.

Comment: This was my issue. I opted for moving `drop procedure if exists sp_xyz;` to outside the `delimiter //` block.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to reproduce this error with MySQL and phpmyadmin:

```
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

[image]
On this version of MySQL:

```
el@apollo:~$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

With the following SQL run through the phpmyadmin query window:

```
use my_database;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE foo()
BEGIN
select 'derp' as 'msg';
END $$

CALL foo()$$           <----Error happens here, with or without delimiters.
```

I couldn't get the error to happen through the MySQL terminal, so I think it's a bug with phpmyadmin.

It works fine on the terminal:

```
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> use my_database$$ create procedure foo() begin select 'derp' as 'msg'; end $$ call foo() $$
Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
+------+
| msg  |
+------+
| derp |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I think the bug has something to do with changing the delimiters mid-query within phpmyadmin.

**Workaround:** Slow down there, cowboy, and run your SQL statements one at a time when using phpmyadmin.  phpmyadmin is "single task bob", he can only do one job.

Answer (score 2):

The possible reason is that mysql client in your code is not thread safe, i encountered the same error when I call mysqldb in python, I have one mysql interface, used in 2 threads, the error happens. In this situation, you need to create more mysql interfaces along with threads.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue on phpMyAdmin 4.8.6

Issue: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14614

Pull-Request: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/pull/15234

The patch: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/pull/15234/files#diff-de1b7e9dd5969db226563678c658ea67

The patch consists into and if [mysqli_more_results](https://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.more-results.php)
then a call to [mysqli_next_result](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.next-result.php)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the 'Begin' keyword, and during compilation MySQL is confused, this should work:

```
DELIMITER ;;
Create procedure sp_test()
    BEGIN
       select * from name_table;
    END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are multiple sources for this issue.  None of the posted answers worked in my case,  I found that in my case I had selects and updates on a table in my stored procedure,  the same table had an update trigger which was being triggered and sending the procedure into an infinite loop.  Once the bug was found the error went away.

I also reproduced the issue in the case where I had a select which was calling a function which modified the table.  It makes sense that these types of recursive calls could create issues.  The issues were solved by updating a tmp table and at the end updating the original table from the tmp table.

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter ;;
Create procedure sp_test()

  select * from name_table;
end ## no end here, must add ;; after end. should be 
delimiter ;;
Create procedure sp_test()

  select * from name_table;
end ;;
```

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered this problem with a C API.

I found the solution with the last example above, which speaks of delimiters.

```
use my_database;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE foo()
BEGIN
select 'derp' as 'msg';
END $$

CALL foo()$$
```

My code executes a stored procedure then tests the return.
I use correctly the mysql_free_result().

Since I have not added a select clause "into" in the procedure, this error occurred.

The last example above is in the same case.

I have deleted the select and since it's ok.

Alex

Answer (score -1):

I just got the same error from phpMYadmin when calling a user function I'm working on.

mysql console says however:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'latitude' in 'field list'
```

...which is absolutely correct, it was misspelled in the field list, so a statement was referencing an undefined variable.

I'd have to conclude that

```
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

from phpMYadmin is a rather non-specific error, than in many cases, if not most, is just obscuring the real problem, and one should not spend too much time trying to make sense out of it.

Answer (score -1):

You have this problem apparently because both statements are executing simultaneously . The only workaround I have found is to close the connection after the sp and execute the other statement on a new one.  Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527466/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now-sql).

Answer (score -1):

This was happening to me because a function within an procedure gave a value back that wasn't allocated to a variable.

The solution was:

```
select function .... INTO @XX;
```