# #2014 error - mysql stored procedure - mamp

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, mamp

I've just installed mamp 3. It has mysql version 5.5.34. I'm managing the database with phpmyadmin version 4.1.12 which comes with mamp 3.

Whenever I try and call a stored procedure I get the error:

```
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I've tried a variety of stored procedures, including ones I've copied from online so I can confidently say it's not a problem with my queries.

Nevertheless:
To create the stored procedure:

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE get()
 BEGIN
    SELECT *  FROM user;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

This executes successfully.

To call the stored procedure:

```
CALL get()
```

This gives the output of:

```
Error
SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit


 SELECT
            s.SCHEMA_NAME,
            s.DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME
               FROM `information_schema`.SCHEMATA s
                GROUP BY BINARY s.SCHEMA_NAME
                ORDER BY BINARY `SCHEMA_NAME` ASC
MySQL said: Documentation

#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the error said `you can't run this command now` so it mean you can run it later :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891179/mysql-error-2014-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Comment: @Mihai I saw that post. But Im not calling the procedure in php yet. I'm just trying to get it working inside phpmyadmin.

Comment: Might also be a phpmyadminbug try another client