# Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, nested

have looked through the forums already but have been unable to solve this problem:
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now SQL

My query is:

```
SELECT Car.*, Building.*, CarType.* 
FROM Car 
INNER JOIN Building 
ON Car.BuildingID=Building.BuildingID 
INNER JOIN CarType 
ON Car.CarType=CarType.TypeID 
WHERE Car.CarID <> (SELECT CarID FROM Requests WHERE Status = 'Accepted')
```

Any help appreciated.
thank you

Answer (score 4):

REFER [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html) Here

If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order.

This can happen, for example, if you are using mysql_use_result() and try to execute a new query before you have called mysql_free_result(). It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data without calling mysql_use_result() or mysql_store_result() in between.

You need to use/store result before you can proceed with next query after.

Another alternative is to close the connection and starts it again.