# query result is null from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) database with a table "tb"

```
Column              Type
---------------------------------
id                  int(11)
chainid             int(11)
commission          decimal(10,2)
order_count         int(11)
total_order_value   decimal(10,2)
fromdt              date
todt                date
```

I run this code from my [php](/questions/tagged/php) file

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `tb` WHERE chainid=$row[0];";
error_log("1st : ".$query);

$storeit = mysql_query($query);
error_log("result of query : ".$storeit);

$query = "INSERT INTO `tb` VALUES(null,$row[0],$com,$oc,$ov,'$startdate','$enddate');";
error_log("2nd : ".$query);

$storeit = mysql_query($query);
error_log("result of query : ".$storeit);
```

but there's nothing happens in DB, and the prints in error_log was:

> 1st : DELETE FROM `tb` WHERE chainid=4 AND
>   fromdt='2017-05-01' AND todt='2017-05-31';
>
> result of query :
>
> INSERT INTO `tb`
>   VALUES(null,4,4755.69,94,6793.84,'2017-05-01','2017-05-31');
>
> result of query :

while when I use these two sentences:

```
DELETE FROM `tb` WHERE chainid=4 AND fromdt='2017-05-01' AND todt='2017-05-31';
INSERT INTO `tb` VALUES(null,4,4755.69,94,6793.84,'2017-05-01','2017-05-31');
```

in SQL tab in [phpmyadmin](/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin) they worked perfectly!!

- So, I don't know what is wrong with my code? is there something I can do?

**UPDATE**
after using [tag:mysql_error()] from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

```
function q($query){ 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    if (mysql_errno()) { 
      $error = "MySQL error ".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n<br>When executing:<br>\n$query\n<br>"; 
      error_log($error);
    } 
}
```

and called this function instead, using:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `tb` WHERE chainid=$row[0] AND fromdt='$startdate' AND todt='$enddate';";
$result = q($query);   
$query = "INSERT INTO `tb` VALUES(null,$row[0],$com,$oc,$ov,'$startdate','$enddate');";
$result = q($query);
```

I got these:

> MySQL error 2014: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
>   
> When executing:
>  DELETE FROM `tb` WHERE chainid=4 AND
>   fromdt='2017-05-01' AND todt='2017-05-31';
>
> MySQL error 2014: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
>   
> When executing:
>  INSERT INTO `tb`
>   VALUES(null,4,4755.69,94,6793.84,'2017-05-01','2017-05-31');

**UPDATE 2**

after a little search about:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
>   in [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527466/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now-sql)

I figured out that I have to close connection and start it again. but the problem is I'm using a function to connect database in the beginning of my **function.php** which included in my **header.php** file :

```
function db_connect()
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "dbname";


    @mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password) or die ("error in host connection");
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        mysql_set_charset('utf8_unicode_ci');
    @mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("error in db connection");
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}

db_connect();
```

- So, how to close the connection using **mysql_close();** ?

Comment: `Delete` and `insert` dont return anything. Are the rows gone/inserted? You also shouldn't use `mysql_` functions anymore, use `mysqli` or `pdo` for future developments.

Comment: nothing deleted and nothing inserted at all

Comment: Look for errors, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php.

Comment: Yeah don't use mysql * functions

Comment: after using [tag:mysql_error] I got these: MySQL error 2014: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
<br>When executing:<br>
DELETE FROM `tb` WHERE chainid=4 AND fromdt='2017-05-01' AND todt='2017-05-31';
<br> **AND** MySQL error 2014: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
<br>When executing:<br>
INSERT INTO `tb` VALUES(null,4,4755.69,94,6793.84,'2017-05-01','2017-05-31');
<br>

Comment: Add that to the question please, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46029913/edit.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to close connection before **mysql_query** using:

```
mysql_close();
```

and open a connection again immediately using my function:

```
db_connect();
```

Many thanks to everyone who contributed trying to solve this problem.