# PHP search Using multiple Criteria submitted from a form

Tags: php, search

The error I'm getting is couldn't issue database query commands out of sync. The parameters coming from a search form and I want to search by entering all fields to search or a single field.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE idStudent = ? AND Student_Fname = ? AND Student_Sname = ? AND Program_idProgram = ? AND Class_idClass = ?";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssss', $idStudent,
                           $Student_Fname, $Student_Sname, $Program_idProgram, $Class_idClass);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if($result){  // display results here}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I'm getting : couldn't use database query. Comands out of sync.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891179/mysql-error-2014-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Comment: also: get rid of `@` as it hides useful error handling information

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE idStudent = ? AND Student_Fname = ? AND Student_Sname = ? AND Program_idProgram = ? AND Class_idClass = ?";
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) 
 {  
         $stmt>bind_param("sssss",$idStudent,$Student_Fname,$Student_Sname,$Program_idProgram, $Class_idClass);
         $stmt->execute();
 }
else
{
    /* error handling*/
}
```

For more information check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: This is the remember to accept the answer by click the tick mark which you forgot. @Zweli Golowa