# MySQL Fulltext Search Error Only On Some Queries

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, fulltext-index

when I use fulltext search in my MySQL 5.6 MyISAM table I sometimes get an error but most of the time it works fine.

This query works fine

```
SELECT title, MATCH(title, keywords, description) AGAINST ('background+water+sea') AS 'relevance' FROM `content` WHERE 
MATCH(title, keywords, description) AGAINST ('background+water+sea');
```

But this one doesn't

```
SELECT title, MATCH(title, keywords, description) AGAINST ('background+water+sea+blue') AS 'relevance' FROM `content` WHERE 
MATCH(title, keywords, description) AGAINST ('background+water+sea+blue');
```

They are basically the same only the second also asks for "blue". There are over 100,000 lines in the table. It gives me "#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" in phpMyAdmin and "Got error -1 from storage engine" if run on a website.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem occurs only when you run from website? If you run the script on phpmyadmin or whatever you are using, do you get the same error?

Comment: If I run it in phpMyAdmin I get "#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" error message. If I run it on a website I get "Got error -1 from storage engine" error message

Comment: Seems to match this bug in phpMyAdmin: https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3475/ It is reported fixed in PMA 3.5. What version are you using?

Comment: I've never heard of the "Got error -1" issue coming from MyISAM. It's always associated with InnoDB. Can you use `SHOW CREATE TABLE content;` on your website and confirm which ENGINE this table uses? Also run `SELECT @@global.innodb_force_recovery;` and confirm it is zero (0).

Comment: This is the result: CREATE TABLE `content` (
 `ID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `keywords` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `IDX_srch` (`title`,`keywords`,`description`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: @@global.innodb_force_recovery is 0

Comment: What's the script for the tables you are using?

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I understood. In phpMyAdmin I use this command in SQL tab.

Comment: Ond more question, have you tried a text different from both cases mentioned in your question?

Comment: Yes, I tried many. and I'm really desperate because I simply cannot figure it out. Here are some examples: background+water+ocean+blue ERROR,
background+water+sea+red ERROR,
background+water+sea+green ERROR,
red+water+sea+blue OK,
red+water+sea+food OK,
background+water+sea+food ERROR,
yellow+water+sea+food OK,
background+red+sea+food ERROR,
background+red+ocean OK,
background+sea+ocean OK,
background+sea+ocean+blue OK

Answer (score 0):

From [MySQL 5.6 manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commands-out-of-sync.html):

> If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in
>   your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order.
>
> This can happen, for example, if you are using mysql_use_result() and
>   try to execute a new query before you have called mysql_free_result().
>   It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data
>   without calling mysql_use_result() or mysql_store_result() in between.

THis error occurs in PHPMyAdmin sometimes if you execute two or more statements at a time. Check [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891179/mysql-error-2014-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now) with a similar problem.

Unfortunately, that's all I can suggest without knowing about the code that calls all of this. If it will not solve the problem, you can share more details

Comment: This is the whole command, nothing else. SELECT title, MATCH(title, keywords, description) AGAINST ('background+water+sea+blue') AS 'relevance' FROM `content` WHERE 
MATCH(title, keywords, description) AGAINST ('background+water+sea+blue'); If I delete the word "blue" it's executed successfully.