# "Commands out of sync" error when trying to execute a procedure in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql-8.0

When executing below code in phpMyAdmin:

```
use db;
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS McaTest3$$
CREATE PROCEDURE McaTest3()

BEGIN 

SELECT
cl.*
FROM `condition_library` cl
     LEFT JOIN condition_custom cc on cl.condition_library_id = cc.condition_library_id
                                  and cc.active = 1
                                  AND (cc.permit_application_id = 20231 OR cc.permit_id = NULL)
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(cl.`condition_library_id`, '13070')
  AND cl.active = 1
  and cc.condition_library_id IS NULL;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

call  McaTest3();
```

Getting error:

> Error
>   Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
>   SQL query: Edit Edit
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

This happens when there is no record found in the table which is at `LEFT JOIN`.

When the same is ran in MySQL Workbench: NO ERROR and return empty dataset.

Same procedure when executed from Application (Appian) is failing as well… **Any clues**?

Answer (score 0):

Another question on Stackoverflow answered my issue:

link: [MySQL error #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891179/mysql-error-2014-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)